# Rendering pdf files with laravel

Tags: laravel, iframe, pdf.js

I am facing this problem whereby I want to display pdf file on a view. The error I am currently meeting is

> syntax error unexpected '?>'

Here's a bit of my code

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to(foldername/#../pathtofile)}} width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe >
```

Comment: Could you post your code correctly? It's not readable/visible now.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote at the end of the `src` attribute and that's probably causing the error:

```
<iframe src="{{URL::to(foldername/#../pathtofile)}}" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe >
```

Hope this helped you.